# Styling for various screen resolutions (smart phones, tablets, laptops, etc.)

Tags: android, iphone, css, ipad, tablet

I am trying to design a site that is easily accessible from tablets, smart phones, and desktops, and is equally usable from any device.

After a bit of reading, I found mixed numbers for the iPhone 4 resolution, which is 620px - 760px.

I am aware of using the following CSS to detect the type of `media`. However, the following CSS is not applied on my iPhone 4.

```
//detect smart phone 
@media screen and (min-width:1px) and (max-width:780px) {
    .inner-main-header{border:2px solid brown;}

}
```

Any ideas why this is? any suggestions what I can do in this case? my goal is to simply use one particular CSS for tablets and another for smart phones.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it'd be min-device-width and max-device-width. Also, your pixels look a bit off:

```
//detect smart phone 
@media screen and (max-device-width:640px) {
    .inner-main-header{border:2px solid brown;}

}

//detect tablets
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){
    .inner-main-header{border:2px solid black;} //changed to black just to see difference
}
```

Answer (score 0):

honestly I would use a site like [this](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) to redirect users to appropriate subdomains with their own respective css. If you opt not to do such a thing, I would suggest just using css to scale all the media based on screen size using values such as max-width: 100% and width:auto\9. Another good tutorial would be [this youtube video](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DRSoWg29wPVc&ei=2K-7UauVMKWz0QGDxYDAAQ&usg=AFQjCNFyDDrLP9Vg6eODsGAMuDdfmsXOZw&sig2=xAyulVj0Lbq4USmRtcIHkg&bvm=bv.47883778,d.dmQ) good luck!